# any small practical example for atexit() function in a c program

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I read about `atexit()` function in Unix program and also knew how does it work, however I could not find any situation where I can use it. Can anyone give a small practical C program example where I can use it?

Comment: try 'man atexit' it will provide description as well as example

Answer (score 1):

Consider a program in which you dynamically allocate memory and use some resources like file and the program may exit at many points based on condition then you need to add code to close the file and free the resources at all those possible exit points. But if you use a function atexit() then you can clear those there. its a possible case. so such tasks that you want to be done before the program stops execution can be written and made to be executed at exit.

One problem example can be,
Suppose the program has multiple test conditions and on success of each condition some data is written to a file. And if condition fails the program exits. The data written to the file should be reverted if all conditions are not satisfied. So in such case you can write a function to be called on exit and then that function can check whether acceptable number of conditions are passed using some flag or so and then carryout required operation. This can be done using other ways too but `atexit` function can make the implementation easier or reduce the LOC.

Comment: But the c program closes all the file descriptors before exit and memory resources get free whenever a processes terminates. Is not it, then why do we need add all those stuffs at every exit point?

Comment: @user976754 ya right. when program exits even its memory space is freed. check the example i added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little, rather silly example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static char temp_filename[255] = "/tmp/tempXXXXXX";


static void do_work(void)
{
  /* create a temporary file */
  mkstemp(temp_filename);
  printf("Created temporary file %s\n", temp_filename);

  /* simulate some work */
  sleep(10);
}

static void cleanup(void)
{
  /* remove temporary files, etc. */
  unlink(temp_filename);

  printf("Exiting...\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* register cleanup handler */
  atexit(cleanup);

  printf("Starting...\n");

  /* do some work */
  do_work();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one standard example.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/